# ngc compilation error as typings/index.d.ts' not found

Tags: angular, angular2-aot

I have downloaded the [Tour Of Heroes](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/) app from following github.

I have been successfully run the app with `npm start`

But when I try to run `npm run start-aot`

Then I am getting the following error.

```
angular2-tour-of-heroes@0.1.0 start-aot D:\angular2-to
ur-of-heroes-master

npm run aot && npm run rollup && gulp copy-aot && npm run lite


angular2-tour-of-heroes@0.1.0 aot D:\angular2-tour-of-
heroes-master
ngc -p tsconfig-aot.json

Error: Error File 'D:/angular2-tour-of-heroes-master/typ
ings/index.d.ts' not found.
    at Object.check (D:\angular2-tour-of-heroes-master\n
ode_modules\@angular\tsc-wrapped\src\tsc.js:31:15)
    at Object.main (D:\angular2-tour-of-heroes-master\no
de_modules\@angular\tsc-wrapped\src\main.js:26:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\angular2-tour-of-heroes-ma
ster\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\main.js:16:9)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
Compilation failed
```

In package.json following are the dependency

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "~2.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "~2.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^2.2.1",
    "@angular/router": "~3.1.0",
    "@angular/upgrade": "~2.1.0",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.1.5",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "systemjs": "0.19.39",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.25"
  }
```

Comment: Which version of a2 are you using???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AoT issues have been fixed now. See [here](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular2-tour-of-heroes/issues/93) for more. The easiest thing to do will be to clone the repo again.

Comment: I am looking for a good angular2 seed project. Can you please help?

Comment: @ParthaSarathiGhosh the way Angular 2 is going I use [Angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) for my projects now over using any of the SystemJs or WebPack seed projects. There is also a good getting start tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uBRK6cTr4Vk).